# MSVC 2017 missing libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_66.lib error

Tags: visual-c++, boost, cmake

I'm trying to create a dynamic library on Windows but I have a problem with Boost, I keep getting this error

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_66.lib'
```

The thing is, according to this http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries the two librairies are supposed to be header only header only

the cmake i'm using

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

project(mod_autoindex)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
SET( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}")
SET( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE "${OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}")

SET (BOOST_ROOT "C:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_66_0")
SET (BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "${BOOST_ROOT}/boost")

if (UNIX)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -W -Wall -Wextra")
    set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
else()
    set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
endif()

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories("../../include")
include_directories("../../include/sza")
include_directories("./include")


file(GLOB_RECURSE CPP_SRCS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE HEADERS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.hpp)

set(SOURCE_FILES ${CPP_SRCS} ${HEADERS})
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME})
```

Any idea of wrang am i doing wrong ?

cmake output for `cmake . -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"`

```
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.11.25547.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.11.25547.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.11.25503/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.11.25503/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.11.25503/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.11.25503/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Boost version: 1.65.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   system
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/theo/Desktop/cpp_zia/modules/mod_autoindex
```

So the solution generation seems to work fine, but after that, when I try to build `MSBuild mod_autoindex.sln` i get the following error

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-gd-1_65_1.lib' [C:\Users\theo\
Desktop\cpp_zia\modules\mod_autoindex\mod_autoindex.vcxproj]
```

@update here is my current cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

project(mod_autoindex)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
SET( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}")
SET( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE "${OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}")

set(BOOST_ROOT "C:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_65_1")
set(Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS 1.65.1)

set(BOOST_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem REQUIRED)

if (UNIX)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -W -Wall -Wextra")
    set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
else()
    set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
endif()

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories("../../include")
include_directories("../../include/sza")
include_directories("./include")


file(GLOB_RECURSE CPP_SRCS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE HEADERS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.hpp)
MESSAGE( STATUS "BOOST libraries: " ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${CPP_SRCS} ${HEADERS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Answer (score 3):

Many `Boost` libraries indeed are header only, but `filesystem` is not.

Instead of doing things manually I would use the `CMake` way of adding library dependencies by using the appropriate find_package module:

```
set(BOOST_ROOT "C:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_65_1")
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
...
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

`Boost` binaries for your compiler can be downloaded at https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/

If `CMake` does not find your `Boost` installation (`CMake 3.10.2` versions FindBoost.cmake module does know about versions up to `Boost 1.65.1`) you can try to add before the `find_package` call

```
set(Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS 1.66.0)
```

**but**

`Boost` changed its naming scheme starting from version `1.66.0`. `CMake` up to version 3.10.2 does not know this scheme and therefore cannot handle it. You need to use `Boost 1.65.1` instead.

***Edit according to the comment by @ComicSansMS:***

Do not hardcode the `Boost` path to your `CMakeLists.txt` instead set it per environment variable `BOOST_ROOT` or provide it as argument to your `CMake` call.

So go to your project path (the path where your `CMakeLists.txt` is stored)

```
mkdir build
cd build
```

and either do

```
set BOOST_ROOT=C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_65_1
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 15 2017"
```

or call

```
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -DBOOST_ROOT="C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_65_1"
```

Later you can use the buildmode of `CMake` to build your entire project

```
cmake --build . --target ALL_BUILD --config Release -- /nologo /verbosity:minimal /maxcpucount
```

Comment: Or you type the names of the libs by hand in CMakeCache.txt

Comment: after installing `boost 1.65.1` and with your cmake example i still get an error :   `Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.65.1

  Boost include path: C:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_65_1

  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_filesystem

  Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
  need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
  to the location of Boost.`

Comment: Where are `.lib` suppose to be in the boost directory, I can't find them manually :/ I installed the lib using the exe provided, should I run `boostrap.bat` too ?

Comment: No, bootstrap setup the necessary tools for building the Boost package. What package did you download and install? What generator are you using for your `CMake` call? Did you delete the `CMakeCache.txt` file before adding the proposed changes? The libraries should be in the lib-msvc-14.1 directory if you build 32 bit or in the lib64-msvc-14.1 directory for 64 bit.

Comment: And what CMake version are you using? You may want to add the `set(Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS 1.65.1)` before your `find_package` call and clear the CMakeCache.txt file again.

Comment: @vre I'm not specifiying the generator. I tried to remove `CMakeCache.txt` along with all cmake generated files, got the same error. So, I'm supposed to have for example `C:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_65_1/lib64-msvc-14.1` ? I don't have that :/

Comment: Can you post the output of your `cmake` call ? Are you trying to build 64 bit or 32 bit? for 64 bit the cmake call is `cmake . -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"` and for 32 bit   `cmake . -G "Visual Studio 15 2017"`

Comment: Just another wild guess: try adding `set(BOOST_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON) set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)` before your `find_package(Boost ...)` call. this should find the static multi threaded Boost libraries.

Comment: Please don't hardcode `BOOST_ROOT` in your CMake scripts. This is supposed to be set by the user invoking CMake, not the script itself. As a matter of fact, you can just set the `BOOST_ROOT` environment variable for the same effect. And note that Boost 1.66 is [already supported on CMake master](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/master/Modules/FindBoost.cmake). If you don't mind patching your local install, you can just replace the find script of a CMake 3.10 installation with the new one.

Comment: @vre Added cmake output in my post ;)

Comment: It seems to work now, because Boost libraries and headers were found?

Comment: @vre cmake generation work as before, I get the error when I try to compile later

Comment: Did you added the `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})` after the `add_executable` call as suggested?

Comment: @vre In my case it is `add_library` but yes, I placed the `target_link_library` just after

Comment: @vre I printed the value of `${Boost_LIBRAIRIES}` and it point to a path where `libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-gd-1_65_1.lib` exist on my system

Comment: Are you using MSVC Developer Studio to build your project? Did you try to clear the CMakeCache.txt again and did a full rebuild? The cache is frequently the reason for such a weird behaviour. Or better, clean the entire build dir and do a clean rebuild.

Comment: @vre I do a full clean rebuild each time

Comment: Ok. just wanted to be sure you do. Can you post the current state of your CMakeLists.txt again? Just append it as update.

Comment: @vre Just added my current cmake ;)

Comment: Rereading your update, I saw you are using MSBuild to build the project. So you can use the buildmode of CMake. Running from build directory after configuration `cmake --build . --target ALL_BUILD --config Release -- /nologo /verbosity:minimal  /maxcpucount` should build your entire project. And I had a typo in Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS, Boost starts with a capital all others letters are lowercase.

Comment: @vre Thanks, this is nice ! But I get the same error :/

Comment: Then please remove all the things related to ...Output_Directory from your CMakeLists.txt. ${OUTPUT_DIRECTORY} is undefined and may cause problems.

Comment: @vre Tried without `output_directory` related options, same error

Comment: It should read `include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})` note the `S` at the end. Try to further strip down your project and remove the CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD if you are not dependend on. And try to remove the UNIX settings.

Comment: @vre This is weird, i've made no changes to the cmake that was working and now it tell me that he can't find `boost_filesystem`...

Comment: So you are trying to link the Boost DLLs, i.e. `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS` is not recognized.

Comment: @vre there was a typo in `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS`, now it search for static libs, but don't find them either. I also tried to set the path to were libs are on my system `set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "C:/local/boost_1_65_1")` with no luck

Comment: `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` is only used to find your Boost installation. You don´t need to set it because you already set BOOST_ROOT. The same applies to `BOOST_INCLUDEDIR`. The installation can be found but somehow the libraries cannot. Is that a typo or are you building in your project directory (`cmake . -G "..."`)? I would avoid that by using a separate directory for the build. This build dir might be located inside of your project dir. See `mkdir build cd build cmake .. -G "..."` sequence in my answer. Doing so you can easily wipe the entire build dir and start a new try.